# Testing a promise reject code path with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a situation where I'm trying to test the code path when a promise rejects. The setup is relatively complicated but I've reduced it down to what is a minimum reproducible example:

```js
let resolver;
let rejecter;

const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolver = resolve;
    rejecter = reject;
});

const f = jest.fn((x) => {
    console.log(x);
});

const run = () => {
    return p
        .then(() => {
            f("resolved");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            f("rejected");
        });
};

beforeEach(() => {
    f.mockClear();
});

// this test passes
test("it should call with resolved when p resolves", async () => {
    run();
    resolver();
    await p;

    expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith("resolved");
});

// this test fails
test("it should call with rejected when p rejects", async () => {
    run();
    rejecter();
    await p;

    expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith("rejected");
});
```

My problem is that, despite the fact that `f` is indeed called with `"rejected"`, the test fails, with the reason

> ```
> thrown: undefined
> ```

My guess at this point is that it has something to do with the fact the promise is rejecting; I had hoped this wouldn't be an issue as it's caught. How can I have this test complete sucessfully?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a `catch` onto the promise `p`:

```js
// this test fails
test("it should call with rejected when p rejects", async () => {
    run();
    rejecter();
    await p.catch(() => {});

    expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith("rejected");
});
```